# Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. for sharedpreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, sharedpreferences

I am writing Junit test for shared preferences but facing below issue

Method

```
public void storeUser(User user) {
        final SharedPreferences userPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userPrefs.edit().putString(USER_ID_KEY, user.getUserID()).apply();
}
```

Junit Class

```
class UserRepoTest {

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepo
    private lateinit var userPrefs: SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = mock()
        userRepo = UserRepo(context)
        userPrefs = mock()
        editor = mock()

    }

    @Test
    fun `check mocked instances are not null`() {
        context assertNotEquals null
        userRepo assertNotEquals null
    }

    @Test
    fun `when store user then load user`() {
        whenever(context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).thenReturn(userPrefs)
        whenever(userPrefs.edit()).thenReturn(editor)
        val user = getUser()
        verify(editor, times(1)).putString(USER_ID_KEY, user!!.userID).apply()
//      verify(userPrefs.edit(), times(1)).putString(USER_ID_KEY, user!!.userID).apply()
        userRepo.storeUser(user)
    }

    private fun getUser(): User? {
        return User().apply {
            userID = "test@yopmail.com"
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val USER_PREFS = "userprefs"
        const val USER_ID_KEY = "UserID";
    }

}
```

but getting below error not sure why its saying not invoked

```
Wanted but not invoked:
editor.putString(
    "UserID",
    "test@yopmail.com"
);
-> at com.example.UserRepoTest.when store user then load user(UserRepoTest.kt:41)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Answer (score 0):

Order is important. Call the action `storeUser()` before you try to `verify` what it did.

Comment: Already tried it but no luck.